# how to delete empty box in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i am using wordpress to build a website the problem is that i create a form to user input but now the webpage display the form and under it it display a box includes edit  like this screeshot

[image]

i need to know how to delete this box 
this box doesn't exist in my code its in the wordpress native code so where to find it although i already comment

this line of code

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );
```

where this code show the default template of the page from **page.php** file

## code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package personalio
 */

        /*
        Template Name: ajwa2template
        */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">


            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            ?>
             <!--**********************************-->  

<html>

<head>
  <title>Form Validation</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified BootStarp CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("#textarea").hide()
      jQuery("#droplistID").change(function() {
        jQuery(this).val() == 'select' ? jQuery("#textarea").hide() : jQuery("#textarea").show();
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" id="myform" action="#" onsubmit="return submitForm();" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-datam">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name" class="col-md-4">Date *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Title" class="col-md-4">Title *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="phone" placeholder="Enter the Title" required/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  ">
                  <label for="category" class="col-md-4">select Category *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select name="droplist" id="droplistID">
                           <option id = "option1" value="select" selected>Select</option>
                           <option id = "option2" value="category 1">category 34</option>
                           <option id = "option3" value="category 2">category 2</option>
                           <option id = "option4" value="category 3">category 3</option>
                       </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div id="textarea">
                  <div class="form-group  ">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <textarea cols="60" rows="15" placeholder="enter a text "> </textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group  ">
                  <label for="image" class="col-md-4">Select Image </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
          <center>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
          </center>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>


<!--***************************************************-->   
            <?php
                //get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;



            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
//get_sidebar();
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to use this in your global css file:

```
.edit-link { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Or, more better from php, in the functions.php file of your theme try:

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_link', '__return_false' );
```

I don't know your exact setup.

Comment: i added your answer  but this code is only delete the link **edit** and not the box

Comment: Can you tell me which Wordpress theme you are using so I could attempt to replicate?

Comment: @ Digital angel i am using personalio theme